# A way to mimic the "share a link to this answer" dialog from a user script?

Tags: discussion, greasemonkey, scripts

I would like to make a browser "user script" (like Greasemonkey etc) that can pop open a window with a text field for the user to select and copy so they can paste it elsewhere.

I want to match the site and there's already the "share a link to this answer" dialog:

[image: "share a link to this answer" dialog]

Is there any way to call this code from a user script? Is the code available somewhere where I can make my own version of it?

**Is there generally a "best" way a user script to mimic a piece of Stack Exchange GUI like this?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there isn't.

We don't guarantee the javascript interfaces won't change (or that that dialog won't be radically altered).  Generally speaking, if you want to mimic a piece of our UI you'll just have to re-implement it if you want it to be stable.